# how to round up value if more than 0.3 in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, rounding

I have table which the value is float, and I want to round up the value to integer if the value is more than 0.30

the columns look like this:

```
weight
2.31
2.50
2.76
2.45
```

I use `cast(round(weight,0) as int)` to round up the weight but it rounds up 2.31 and 2.35 to 2 while I expect to be rounded up to 3. So if it's more than 0.3 then it should be rounded up while if it's less than 0.3 then it should rounded down

How can I do this in redshift sql?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding `0.2` to the weight then `round()` :

```
cast(round(weight + 0.2) as int)
```

[Demo on mysql](https://dbfiddle.uk/95RaBjVw)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this with [FLOOR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FLOOR.html) and `+0.70` to get values you want

`cast(floor(weight + 0.70) as int)`

Comment: i got this error ```ERROR: function floor(numeric, integer) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts``` when I run the syntax, anything I should fix?

Comment: Sorry, Floor takes just one arguments, I forget to remove second argument. I update my answer with correct version.